# How to join two table with partial match using whole words

Tags: sql-server

Please help to refine my View in order to join two tables with partial match of the whole word list.

In the attached screenshot, ProductID 12 and 36 should not be listed because the whole word in ProductName is not = to "Mix" but SillMix and MixPastora.

```
SELECT dbo.Products.ProductID, dbo.Products.ProductName, dbo.NAMES.FullName
FROM   Products 
INNER JOIN dbo.NAMES ON dbo.Products.ProductName LIKE '%' + dbo.NAMES.FullName + '%'
```

[image]

Comment: This type of query is usually problematic. It pretty much requires using a string splitter so you can isolate each word, then join on the portion of the string. It is almost always a sign that something in the architecture needs to be changed.

Comment: Man people around here really like that -1 button. I don't think this question deserves a downvote. It has some room for improvement but this type of thing is challenging and fairly common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need values of FullName as a whole to comparison?
Try change the ON condition like this:

```
dbo.Products.ProductName LIKE '%' + dbo.NAMES.FullName + '%'
```

To

```
dbo.Products.ProductName LIKE '% ' + dbo.NAMES.FullName + ' %' OR
dbo.Products.ProductName LIKE '% ' + dbo.NAMES.FullName OR    
dbo.Products.ProductName LIKE dbo.NAMES.FullName + ' %'
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the value to find is at the beginning or the end of the string.

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much jambonick!

Comment: You're welcome. If you wish accept this answer. Still it will work correctly only if FullName is every time one word

Comment: This updated version will produce the desired results. This may not scale very well to large datasets because it will force index scans instead of seeks because it is nonSARGable. But for smaller datasets this will work quite nicely.

Comment: You guys are fantastic! Sean your solution seem impressive but because of my limited knowledge of SQL server I will need some time to understand it. If I am allowed, not that I am able to select the correct record in table Products,  how can I transform SELECT code to update a column in Products called Score and update it with the value of 5?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can do this. I am making use a string splitter for this which can have some serious negative performance impact if you have a lot of data. This splitter is pretty darn fast though.

Here is the splitter.

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 0 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "zero base" and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                 SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@pString,1))) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT t.N+1
                   FROM cteTally t
                  WHERE (SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter OR t.N = 0) 
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString,s.N1,ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000))
   FROM cteStart s
;
```

This splitter is the one created by Jeff Moden and perfected by the community at sql server central. You can read the full article here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

There are several other options for splitters. One of the best articles on alternatives can be found here. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Now that we have covered the splitter lets set up some data and see how this thing works.

```
declare @Products table(ProductID int, ProductName varchar(100))
declare @Names table(FullName varchar(100))

insert @Products (ProductID, ProductName) values
(52, 'Filo Mix')
, (36, 'Inagd SillMix')
, (2, 'Mix Chang')
, (12, 'Queso Manchego La MixPastora')

insert @Names
select 'Mix'

SELECT p.ProductID
    , p.ProductName
    , n.FullName
FROM  @Products p
INNER JOIN @Names n ON p.ProductName LIKE '%' + n.FullName + '%'
cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(p.ProductName, ' ') x 
where x.Item = n.FullName
```